# Spring JUnit files loading issue

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am using the below piece of code for JUnit test of my Spring maven application

```
private static BeanFactory servicefactory = null;
private static BookingProcessService bookingProcessService;
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception{
    try{
        String[] configFiles = {"applicationcontext-Service.xml","applicationcontext-Hibernate.xml","applicationContext-dao.xml"};
        ClassPathXmlApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(configFiles);
        servicefactory = (BeanFactory) appContext;
        bookingProcessService = (BookingProcessService) servicefactory.getBean("bookingProcessService");            
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

While building my project using maven, I am getting some errors.The bean named **bookingProcessBusiness** is not creating may be because the spring configuartion files are not properly loaded.

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Please provide exact exception you are getting
2. Yes, the exception that you are swallowing instead of throwing further and letting JUnit know something is wrong. Don't do this:

   ```
   }catch (Exception e){
     e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```
3. Why won't you use built-in [Spring support for integration testing](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html)?

   ```
   @RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
   @ContextConfiguration(locations={"applicationcontext-Service.xml","applicationcontext-Hibernate.xml","applicationContext-dao.xml"})
   public class BookingProcessServiceTest {

       @Autowired
       private BookingProcessService bookingProcessService;

   }
   ```

   No glue code, no `static`s.